# ServiceNow API call in Dotnet application

Tags: .net, servicenow

I am created custom application in Service Now. In Dotnet application shall i use API call for the ServiceNow custom application. Kindly guide me or if it is possible or not.

Regards,
Premkumar.T

Comment: Hi Team, Kindly guide me, Service Now is implemented with Dotnet. If it is possible?

Comment: Hi Team any solution?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceNow's APIs are publicly documented. If you're trying to get/set data in ServiceNow from your .NET app, you'll want to follow this guide: [API Explorer Demo](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/learning-plans/orlando/technology_partner_program/app_store_learnv2_rest_orlando_introduction_to_the_rest_api_explorer)

Additional examples: [Inbound Web Service Examples](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/integrate/examples/concept/c_InboundWebServiceExamples.html)

[Full Table API Documentation](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/rest/c_TableAPI)